How can I add all jar files from my lib folder to my maven project?
I have many maven projects packaged as Jar files and I need those projects that interact with each other to be available in my web project which is also a maven project.
I need the classes inside those jar files to be reachable by the web project that I'm developing.
there are a lot of jar files in my lib folder, it would be very counter productive inserting each dependency in the pom file because the jar files are still under development and version could change at any time.
I tried the resources plugging
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/lib</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>

But this didn't work.

This question has a really good answer here. My guess is that the helper script option best suits your needs.
